Trouble publishing contract source code in Brownie: ConnectionError 403
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to deploy a contract using Brownie and publish its source code to Etherscan. The deployment itself is successful, but I'm unable to publish the contract source code due to a ConnectionError with status code 403.
Here's the relevant portion of the error message:
Brownie v1.19.5 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieFundMeProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts/deploy.py::main'...
Transaction sent: 0x50046333f9033506759526a0b24e9bab8e7d9ca21ec925b9b4362d3d90162136
  Max fee: 0.001642324 gwei   Priority fee: 0.000477748 gwei   Gas limit: 400846   Nonce: 11
  FundMe.constructor confirmed   Block: 5643342   Gas used: 360379 (89.90%)   Gas price: 0.000999976 gwei
  FundMe deployed at: 0xAbC91d45877CF82E34bc982F5737DD16bA34F3bB

  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 110, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 10, in main
    deploy_fund_me()
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 6, in deploy_fund_me
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account}, publish_source=True)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 553, in __call__
    return tx["from"].deploy(
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 573, in deploy
    contract.publish_source(deployed_contract, silent=silent)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 410, in publish_source
    raise ConnectionError(
ConnectionError: Status 403 when querying https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/: 

I've already checked my API key and verified that it's correctly configured in my Brownie project settings. Additionally, I've ensured that the API key has the necessary permissions for publishing contract source code.
Api Testing: https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae&tag=latest&apikey=V3SMDEYQ6ZDC311P341NQB8UMI67RKZU6N
I've attempted to retry the deployment script multiple times, but the issue persists. I've also confirmed that there are no ongoing service disruptions or maintenance activities on Etherscan's end.
Here's the deployment script I'm using:
from brownie import accounts, config, FundMe
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account

def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account}, publish_source=True)
    print(f"Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}")
    
def main():
    deploy_fund_me()

And here is .env file
export PRIVATE_KEY = XXXX
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID = XXXX
export ETHERSCAN_TOKEN = V3SMDEYQ6ZDC311P341NQB8UMI67RKZU6N


Could anyone provide insights into what might be causing this ConnectionError with status code 403? Are there any additional troubleshooting steps I can take to resolve this issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Were you able to publish and verify directly via the Sepolia Etherscan UI ?

Brownie is not really supported anymore so may be hard to find help. If you modify network/contract.py to print the api_key say on line 405, does it return the key as you expect?
